# How to put widgets together using Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the code that I wrote to have two button and a text entry in my GUI:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

top = Tkinter.Tk()
b1 = Button ( top, text = "Hack it!", height = 10, width = 20)
b2 = Button ( top, text = " Clone! ", height = 10, width = 20)
t = Text(top,width=60,height=40)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)
t.grid(row=1)
top.mainloop()
```

And this is the result:
[image]

But what I want is this:

[image]

How can I have it? (a label above the text entry is ideal too)

Is there any way to make the text entry read only?

Comment: You can find most of the properties and methods of Tkinter widgets here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `columnspan` [option of grid()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) to make text extend more than one column.
To make text read-only, simply set `state` [option of text widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.config-method) to `"disabled"`.

```
import Tkinter as tk

top = tk.Tk()
b1 = tk.Button(top, text="Hack it!", height=10, width=20)
b2 = tk.Button(top, text=" Clone! ", height=10, width=20)
t = tk.Text(top, width=60, height=40, state="disabled") #makes text to be read-only
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)
t.grid(row=1, columnspan=2) #this makes text to span two columns
top.mainloop()
```

About label, just place it to `row=1` and move text to `row=2`.